# Get value from table after validate Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a simple table:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="">                   
    <input type="text" name='first_name' data-validation="alphanumeric" />              
    <select name='custom_quantity'>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Using a simple validation script:

```
<script>
    (function($, window) {    
        var dev = '.dev'; // window.location.hash.indexOf('dev') > -1 ? '.dev' : '';

        window.applyValidation = function(validateOnBlur, forms, messagePosition) {
            if ( !forms )
                forms = 'form';
            if ( !messagePosition )
                messagePosition = 'top';

            $.validate({
                form : forms,
                validateOnBlur : validateOnBlur,
                errorMessagePosition : messagePosition,
                scrollToTopOnError : true,
                onSuccess : function($form) {                                                           
                    first_name = $( "#form input[name='first_name']" ).val();
                    select = $( "#form select[name='custom_quantity']" ).val();
                    alert( "Your: " + first_name + ' ' + select +  " values." );

                    return false;
                }
            });
        };

        window.applyValidation(true, '#form', 'element');
    })(jQuery, window);
</script>
```

Validation works fine, and after inputing some text in the input field and selecting one of values from the select tag, I don't get any message on alert.

Also, Firebug console doesn't show any error.

Is this way of getting value from a form valid?

```
first_name = $( "#form input[name='first_name']" ).val();
```

Comment: `" #form` ...have you tried removing the leading space from the selector?

Answer (score 0):

```
first_name = $( "#form input[name='first_name']" ).val();
select = $( "#form select[name='custom_quantity']" ).val();
```

I think this line returns an array, try selecting the first element

```
first_name = $( "#form input[name='first_name']" )[0].val();                    
select = $( "#form select[name='custom_quantity']" )[0].val();
```